# How does one query inside a for loop using parse?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, ionic-framework, relationship

I have an Ionic application where I am searching for a user. When the search returns a result, I want to be able to follow or unfollow that user.

```
 //search
$scope.searchPro = function(){
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
var searchinpu = $('#search-input').val();
var searchinput = searchinpu.toLowerCase();
query.equalTo("username", searchinput);  // find all the relative users

query.find({
  success: function(results) {
    //Return User and foreach loop
    var searchcon = "";
    for (var i in results){
            var username = results[i].get("username");
            var image = results[i].get("profile_pic");
            var postimage = image.url();
            var curUser = Parse.User.current();
             //Second Query get follow button
            var cquery = new Parse.Query(Activity);
            cquery.matches("fromUser", curUser);  // find if he or she follows or not
            cquery.matches("toUser", username);  // find if he or she follows or not
            cquery.find();

            var button = "<button class='button button-outline button-lighter follow'>Follow</button>";
            searchcon += "<div class='search-re'>";
            searchcon += "<div class='search-re-view'><img src="+postimage+"></img></div>";
            searchcon += "<div class='search-re-small'><img src="+postimage+"></img></div>";
            searchcon += "<h3>@"+username+"</h3>";
            searchcon += button;
            searchcon += "</div>";
        }
```

The searching for the user and returning a result works fine.The problem is the the second query. I am not able to check whether that the current user has followed the searched user. Therefor, I can not differentiate whether the button should be a follow button or a unfollow button.
Is there a way to display this button?

Comment: why are you manually generating all this html in the first place? Your view should be driven by scope data models and those queries will likely be asynchronous. Suggest you study some angular tutorials

Comment: you might want to rethink the schema a bit regarding the relation [user] follows [user].... its a MANY :: MANY relation that you may want to  implement outside Parse.User class. For example a class with an inferred relation (Follows) could have just 2 , fields that are pointers back to respective entities in Parse.User... NewClass.followed, NewClass.follower... since they are both pointers , you can use an include to pull the entire User rows for the 2 users in the relation

Comment: My apologies i'm fairly new to parse and ionic, so basically you would have three classes, the user class, a newclass.followed, and a newclass.follower if I got your jist? Or is that two classes user and newclass?